# Tool for extracting a interface out of a class

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generate PHP Interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8247482/generate-php-interfaces)

As I want to program against a interface I am looking for a tool that can extract a Interface out of a class.

Suppose I a have a class like this:

```
<?php
    class Foo
    {
      public function Bar()
      {
      }
    }
?>
```

then I want the result to be this:

```
interface IFoo
{
  public function Bar();
}
```

Obvious, for a simple class it is very easy by hand. But I want to extract a interface from the [fpdf class](http://www.fpdf.org/), and that is a lot of work.

Any tools for this?

note: In VS2010 this is very easy, just a few clicks.

Comment: I dont know any free solutions, but you can pay me to do that ;-)

Comment: You want to port every public method of a class to a corresponding bodyless one in a new interface? Just use Reflection to write up a new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a PHP based library containing a commandline tool as well that is able to extract interfaces out of a class definition:

- [InterfaceDistiller](https://github.com/gooh/InterfaceDistiller)

This is a more convenient variant of what has been outlined in the related question [Extracting just the interface from a PHP application, for code completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839677/extracting-just-the-interface-from-a-php-application-for-code-completion).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like c# and you talk about vs2010, but question tags are about php?

In case the labels are wrong, Resharper is what you need. It does it and a lot more.

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

It's not free, but they have a time limited version to try.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear, I adjusted the question. (It is for PHP)